# Why does BinaryHeap require Ord?

Tags: rust, comparator, binary-heap, partial-ordering

I am using the standard [`BinaryHeap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BinaryHeap.html) as part of an algorithm where I need to retrieve the largest object (via some definition of largest).  It could be possible that two non-equivalent elements are both equally large (and hence their relative order in the binary heap does not matter) - for example, I might be only interested in sorting on a single field of a multi-field struct.

Because of this, it would be somewhat unusual to have my type implement `Ord` and `Eq`.  Instead, I should probably implement `PartialOrd` and `PartialEq` only.  But, alas, `BinaryHeap` requires its elements to be `Ord`!  Why is this so, and what is the most idiomatic way to use `BinaryHeap` with such types?

(As an aside, in C++, I would fairly easily write a custom comparator type in such a situation, and template the priority queue on the comparator type.  So I don't think what I want to do is mathematically or algorithmically wrong.)

Comment: `Ord` does not mean that no two values compare equal -- it only means that no two values are *incomparable*. I see no problem with just implementing `Ord` and `Eq` so that they only compare sizes.

Comment: If you don't want to implement `Ord` directly on the struct, wrap it in a newtype and implement `Ord` for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PartialOrd` gives you asymmetric and transitive ordering, that is `a < b` implies `!(a > b)` and `a < b && b < c` implies `a < c`. `PartialOrd` does *not* require for all elements to actually have a meaningful ordering at all, which is why `PartialOrd::partial_cmp` returns an `Option<Ordering>` where `None` means "I don't know" (notice that this does not impair the aforementioned requirements).

A binary heap requires total ordering for its elements, however, because a binary heap has to have the property that "the key stored in each node is either greater than or equal to (≥) or less than or equal to (≤) the keys in the node's children, according to some total order." (direct quote via Wikipedia).

Only `Ord` gives you asymmetric, transitive and total (exactly one of `a < b`, `a == b` or `a > b`) ordering. The requirement for total order leads to `Ord::cmp` returning a `Ordering`, not a `Option<Ordering>`, because the `None`-case is not allowed.

It is not uncommon the write specific implementations of `PartialOrd` and `Ord` in case you need specific behaviour. There is also the [`educe` crate](https://github.com/magiclen/educe), which allows you to derive a more specific version of `PartialOrd` and `Ord` where certain fields are ignored.